# Second-order correction term in perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, perturbation-theory

I am currently reading an introduction to perturbation theory, and was just reading about the second-order correction term to the energy $E^{(2)}$. My textbook first states that$$H_0\psi^{(2)}+H'\psi^{(1)}=E^{(0)}\psi^{(2)}+E^{(1)}\psi^{(1)}+E^{(2)}\psi^{(0)},$$which I understand. Then, however, it multiplies through by the bra $\langle\psi^{(0)}|$, and concludes that$$E^{(2)}=\langle\psi^{(0)}|H_0-E^{(0)}|\psi^{(2)}\rangle-\langle\psi^{(0)}|H'-E^{(1)}|\psi^{(1)}\rangle.$$This is strange to me, because when I tried to work out the equation myself I concluded that $$E^{(2)}=\langle\psi^{(0)}|H_0|\psi^{(2)}\rangle-\langle\psi^{(0)}|H'|\psi^{(1)}\rangle.$$I don't understand why the $\langle\psi^{(0)}|E^{(0)}|\psi^{(2)}\rangle$ and $\langle\psi^{(0)}|E^{(1)}|\psi^{(1)}\rangle$ terms are even necessary. After all $E^{(1)}$ and $E^{(2)}$ are constants, so it seems like you can simplify $\langle\psi^{(0)}|E^{(0)}|\psi^{(2)}\rangle$ to $E^{(0)}\psi^{(0)}|\psi^{(2)}\rangle=0$, where the last calculation is made using the orthonormality of the eigenstates. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, my calculations make me think that $\langle\psi^{(0)}|E^{(0)}|\psi^{(2)}\rangle=0$, which the textbook doesn't seem to agree with.

Comment: I think your notation is such at $\psi^{(2)}$ is the second-order change in the state. This is not necessarily orthogonal to $\psi^{(0)}$ (the unperturbed state)..

Comment: Oh, so the corrections to the state function aren't perpendicular to the original state function? For some reason, I feel like I read somewhere (in a different book) that they were.

Comment: Cf [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)#Second-order_and_higher-order_corrections).

Comment: @slithy_tove You need to introduce the Dirac Delta function $ E^{(0)} \delta (\psi^{(0)}-\psi^{(2)})$ in order to simplify the term $\langle \psi^{(0)} |E^{(0)}| \psi^{(2)}\rangle  $ term. Then you can apply the orthogonality theorem according to the conditions given.